# Permission denied when pushing to repository with git

Tags: git, ssh, version-control, repository, push

When I am using the command `git push -u origin master`, I get the error

```
Permission denied (publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I am using Windows 10.

I guess I am not logged in correctly.

I have seen the answer at [GIT push: permission denied (public key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660744/git-push-permission-denied-public-key), but I cannot use the command `ssh`. I guess it is because I am on a Windows machine.

Besides, Github says that https is recommended in favor of using ssh.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows machine , then there is an extension called

```
git extension
```

Once you download, then you have to make your ssh file to push or pull from git server using git extension.

You can create your SSH file in your git server account. After that you can try this using git extension

Comment: I get the error `git: 'extension' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`.

Comment: its an GUI application for git server. its not an command. download that application named git extension and configure it. its a simple step process

Comment: [GitExtensions](http://gitextensions.github.io/) is GUI-client (one of) for Git with reasonably smart [SSH-settings](https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#ssh)

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute the command from inside the git repository. i.e.,
the folder which contains the .git file

Comment: I do execute the command from inside the git rep. I have initialized with `git init`, added a new file with `git add README.md`, commited with `git commit -m "commit msg"`, added origin with `git remote add origin git@github.com:username/rep-name.git`, but now I cannot push to the rep