# Git push command

Tags: git

I have a public key with GitHub. Just made it today. I closed Git and launched it back again and now its not pushing my projects. It generates the following error:

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

As well when I try executing the following command: 
git remote add origin 
I get the following message:
fatal: remote origin already exists.

Can someone please help. I have spent a lot of time trying to use suggested solutions on here, but none worked for me. Lastly, do I need to initialize Git to my public key directory and make sure access is successful to GitHub every time I launch Git?

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried already, so we don't suggest duplicate solutions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904339/github-fatal-remote-origin-already-exists

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660744/git-push-permission-denied-public-key

Comment: I had the problem and then I followed the instructions on GitHub to make SSH key. I did and was given access, but still I cant push anything. Its my first time doing this and I don't know what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error 'fatal: remote origin already exists' means that you have already done

```
git remote add origin 'your git repo'
```

To remove the origin, do this:

```
git remote rm origin
```

And redo the command:

```
git remote add origin 'your git repo'
```

Example:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/YourUsername/YourProject.git
```

Also make sure that the repository exists and is created on GitHub, and you have access to it.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I removed the origin and redid the command but instead of using git@github.com:/UserName/Project.git, I used what you gave me: https://github.com/YourUsername/YourProject.git

Comment: In the place of YourUsername and YourProject, you put your github username and your github project.

An example could be mine:

`git remote add origin https://github.com/Li357/SudokuSolver.py`

And if I you could be willing, give me a thumbs and the selected answer :)

Comment: what I meant is gitHub gives the following command:  git remote add origin git@github.com:UserName/Project.git. instead I used: git remote add origin https://github.com/UserName/Project.git. instead of git@github.com I used what you gave me https://github.com

Comment: I gave you thumbs up, but since I am new its saying it wont show until I earn 15 points. I guess I have to go answer some easy programming questions to earn those points lol

Comment: Sure, so if you could give me the repository you are trying to add as a remote I could give you the command to type. You can select it as the best answer :)