# Git hub getting error while push the code in repostory?

Tags: git, github

I have created a new account on GitHub and created a new repository. Now I want to push my localhost project in that repository.

By default it's showing master branch and when I am trying to push code getting this error in command line:

```
git@GitHub.Com: Permission denied (public key).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

These are commands:

```
git add .
git commit -m "this is my first commit"
git pull origin master
```

I am not sure why this error is coming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git push: permission denied (public key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660744/git-push-permission-denied-public-key)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Permission+denied+public+key

Answer (score 1):

Check your public key is appropriately added in your github account.

Then validate remote is added properly.

```
git remote -v
```

After validating the above then try to pull or push.

Comment: "Check your public key is appropriately added in your github account" can you let me know how i can add the key?

Comment: Or use `https` instead of `ssh` (then you can *push* (not pull) using your password)