# Error while pulling and pushing from source tree

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I am able to commit changes from source tree but I get "Permission denied" error.
I suspect it is a password issue but in that case I shouldn't have been able to commit as well.

Any idea what might be the resolution for this issue ?

[image]

Comment: [git push: permission denied (public key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660744/git-push-permission-denied-public-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you had your repository under the HTTPS protocol and once you set the URL origin your repository became to connect under the SSH protocol. Would be possible to generate a key-pair, add the public key to your Bitbucket repository and the private key to your ssh and give it a try.

Comment: It worked. I used "ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id<my file name>"