# git push -u origin master failed with encounter the issue of permission denied

Tags: git, github, rstudio

I create new project in `Rstudio`, and I opened `github` project repository as well. However, I intend to push all my project implementation to `github` page, but `Git` complaints with following error:

```
$ git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to JulaitiShayiding/mspc.git denied to julaiti.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/JulaitiShayiding/mspc.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I used those git command to do this:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
rm -rf .git
git init
git add --all
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin "https://github.com/JulaitiShayiding/mspc.git"
$ git pull --rebase origin master
git push -u origin master
$ git pull origin master
```

**Edit**:

I tried of adding `.gitignore` file by using `git add .gitignore`, but still can't work with solving permission denied problem. The `.gitingore` file has following content:

```
.Rproj.user
.Rhistory
.RData
```

I looked into the related post in `SO`, and tried all of them [git permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857283/permission-denied-error-on-github-push/17857453), but still, can't solve my problem. Can anyone help me out with this issue? How to fix this bug? Any idea? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you do not have permission to push to repository `https://github.com/JulaitiShayiding/mspc.git/`. To push to a repository you either have to be the owner of the repository or you have to be a collaborator of the repository. To do so either go to repository settings and add yourself as a collaborator or ask the owner to add you as a collaborator.

[image]

If it's not your repository and you're not able to get a collaborator you can fork the repository to your account, do some changes and then create a pull request to the original repository. This pull request then has to be accepted by the owner or by a collaborator of the repository.

Comment: @datageek did you provide your GitHub credentials when pushing?

Comment: @datageek try to execute `git remote set-url origin https://yourusername@github.com/user/repo.git` and then you should be prompted for the password when pushing

Comment: @datageek please verify if in your `.gitconfig` (On Windows under `C:\Users\USERNAME\.gitconfig`) the correct `name` and email address are present (Same information you used for registration at GitHub).

Comment: Did you verify what name is specified in your `.gitconfig`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139267/discussion-between-rufer7-and-datageek).