# How to fix Error pushing git repo from vsc even after reading?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

Hey guys I am the owner of my GitHub repo and I have the right login on VSC. I when I searched my problem I came to a few results.

This one:
[Permission denied error on Github Push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857283/permission-denied-error-on-github-push)
this did not help as 1. the guy was not the owner of the repo and he needed to create a fork to fix the problem. I cant fork because I am the admin it says. Also when i use ssh it does not work.

I also came across this
https://github.com/collective/Collective/issues/123
It does not help as it was resolved by another man off the page.

I cant post more links due to stack restricting me but my exact error is:

```
You dont have permission to push 'Thatonerookiedev/full-stack' 
on github create fork?
```

When I push create fork.
It says error see terminal

```
could not see remote repository
```

And when I try again, it says:

```
error upstream already exists
```

But when I go to the GitHub repo no fork is there.

My GitHub desktop wont let me push it shows a fork here though

[image: GitHub Desktop]

Answer (score 0):

ok guys look you must do 2 things

close out of all things follow this answer on here [Git - remote: Repository not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813568/git-remote-repository-not-found)

and go to the computer folder and find your folder you have the repository on
go to view then click show hidden items (look where my mouse is) https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTMZW.jpg and delete the grey-ed .git folder

if you get the error were it wont let you delete close out of every thing but the folder and delete it.

optional but provides best results: then go to the web github repository and delete it. (only works if you are the owner obviously)

You will need to sign into github again on desktop app if you have it and make a new repository. It should work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I would recommend:

- switching to command line (for testing)
- git clone your repository (`git clone https://github.com/Thatonerookiedev/full-stack`)
- switching back to GitHub Desktop and opening that local repository.

If, after creating a local commit, you cannot push, check your `git config --global credential.helper`

It should be set to `manager-core`.

Check the credentials stored for `github.com` with:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https" | git-credential-manager-core get
```

Make sure a [GitHub PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) is stored there as password.